Responding to SettingsBundle Toggle change in background
I have added a toggle switch to the SettingsBundle of my app to turn Cloud storage on or off:
// ...
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
        <key>Enable Cloud Storage</key>
        <string>Enabled</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>kIDCloudStorageEnabled</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
// ...

Then, I am using @Appstorage to perform code (for now only a print statement) when the toggle is changed:
struct AppView: View {
    @AppStorage("kIDCloudStorageEnabled") var kIDCloudStorageEnabled: Bool?

    var body: some View {
           // ...
        }
        .onChange(of: kIDCloudStorageEnabled) { [oldValue = kIDCloudStorageEnabled] newValue in
            debugPrint(newValue)
        }
    }
}

This works, but .onChange is not executed until my app comes back to the foreground.
How can I respond immediately when the toggle switch is flipped?
